# remove subset from list

Tags: python, list, subset

I have two lists A and B.

I want to remove from B all the subsets that start with the (x,y) of A. For example if i have

```
A = [(1,2), (1,3), (1,5)]
B = [(1,2,10), (1,2,20), (1,3,2), (2,6,2)]
```

I want B to be modified as `[(2,6,2)]`

I have tried `B = set(B) - set(A)` but it does not work. Any help?

Comment: Ok, what have you tried?

Comment: You should post some code on what you've tried so far, even though it may cause errors or not produce the desired result.

Comment: @DeepSpace edited

Comment: @EricTruett edited

Comment: _I have tried `B = set(B) - set(A)` but it does not work_ A does not contain any of the same elements as B.  Why would you expect that to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sets work on value, not prefixes, so `set(B) - set(A)` is not even close.

Let's think about this step-by step: iterate through `B` and filter out any item that has a prefix equal to an item in `A`. As a list comprehension, that would look like this:

```
[y for y in B if not any(x == y[:len(x)] for x in A)]
```

If the items in `A` will always have length 2, you can simplify:

```
[y for y in B if y[:2] not in A]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
a = [(1,2), (1,3), (1,5)]
b = [(1,2,10), (1,2,20), (1,3,2), (2,6,2)]
b = [x for x in b if x[0:2] not in a]
# [(2, 6, 2)]
```

[Demo](https://trinket.io/python3/ae9d4dcecb)